# res.redirect('/'); not working after sending data to MongoDb

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send data to MongoDB and after sending the data the page should refresh the site to its homepage.

```
app.post('/info', function(req,res){ 
    var name = req.body.name; 
    var email =req.body.email; 
    var message = req.body.message;

    var data = { 
        "name": name, 
        "email":email, 
        "message":message,
    } 
    db.collection('info').insertOne(data,function(err, collection){ 
        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log("Record inserted Successfully");
        res.redirect('/');

    });

    db.close();

})
```

But this does nothing, data is sent successfully but it's not redirecting.

Even I have tried to return it at the end of function still it's not working.

Any help would be great.

Comment: try db.close(); inside your query, and let us know if this works! Or remove it.

Comment: It didn't work @niranjanharpale

Comment: Are you getting the console output in the console, also try redirecting to google.com.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `res.redirect('/');` with `res.redirect('back')`. It also request back to